# Calling a third party graphql api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, graphql

I have been trying to understand GraphQl and how it is used by reading articles.
I've seen how to create an api via graphQl, however i havent seen an article which demonstrates how a third party would call a graphQl api.

In my experience i've mainly called RESTful api's with `httparty` gem (I work with ruby on rails), which has the following format:
`HTTParty.post(url, headers, body)`.

However how would someone calling a graphQL api make this request? Would they need to install graphql into their application in order to make the request?(ideally everything should be in the api documentation?) or have I misunderstood how graphql works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  In a GraphQL API the clients (third party applications) can make requests by sending a GraphQL query to the server that will return a response in JSON

To make a GraphQL request, the client typically sends a POST request to the GraphQL API endpoint with the JSON payload that contains the GraphQL query.  The request can also include variables, which can be used to pass dynamic data to the query.  Example:

```
    POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer <token>

    {
      "query": "query ($id: ID!) { user(id: $id) { name } }",
      "variables": {
        "id": "123"
      }
    }
```

In this example, the asking GraphQL to return the name of the user with the ID of 123.  The query field contains the GraphQL query and the variables field contains the variable id which is used to fetch the user with the given id

The client does not need to install GraphQL into their application.  The client can use any HTTP client library that supports sending POST Requests with JSON payloads like httparty in Ruby.  The client doesn't need to know anything about the GraphQL schema or types because that info can be found in the API documentation.

A note on GET vs POST requests with GraphQL; it's generally recommended to use POST requests for more complex queries that require variables or mutations.  GET requests are best suited for simple queries that don't require complex input.  The other caveat on GET requests is some GraphQL APIs may not support GET requests so would want to make sure to check the documentation to see what request methods are supported

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.
For some reason i thought that `POST` and `GET` wouldn't be used in the request, because from reading articles, i got the impression that a big plus of graphql was the use of one endpoint, therefore i wasnt sure what verb would be used. But that clears things up!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to install GraphQL, since it is an agnostic specification in a way similar to a RESTful service. GraphQL tells you (in the schema) what you need to send in order to receive your response.

For example, if I were calling a Books API I would send a GET request to get the list of books like this:

```
//request
HTTP GET /books

//response
{[
{
  "bookId":34443,
  "author":"Borges",
  "title":"Otras inquisiciones"
},
{
  "bookId":34445,
  "author":"Borges",
  "title":"Ficciones"
}
]}
```

The difference (one of the many differences, to be precise) is that a GraphQL API lets you choose which data you want, in this case:

```
//GraphQL exposes a single endpoint to the outer world
//request
HTTP POST /graphql 
//body
query{
  allbooks{
    title
  }
}

//response
{[
{
  "title":"Otras inquisiciones"
},
{
  "title":"Ficciones"
}
]}
```

So in your case, you should format your `body` to be in line with the GraphQL API schema you are trying to consume, and send it in an HTTP POST request to the endpoint: `HTTParty.post(url, headers, body)`